# How to add/remove FormControl from a nested FormGroup

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms

```
candidateForm:FormGroup; 
constructor(private fBuilder: FormBuilder){ }

ngOnInit(){
    this.candidateForm = this.fBuilder.group({
      fname: [null, [Validators.required]],
      lname: [null, [Validators.required]],
      address: this.fBuilder.group({
        address1: [null],
        address2: [null],
      })
    })
  }
```

How to add a FormControl named `address3` to the form group `address`? And similarly how to remove them from the same FormGroup?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First you have to get the sub FormGroup from your main FormGroup, and then you could use the addControl and removeControl refrenced in the documentation here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup.

So in your case it would be:

```
//Add:
this.candidateForm.get('address').addControl('address3',[]);

//Remove:
this.candidateForm.get('address').removeControl('address2');
```

Comment: There is no second argument when calling removeControl.

Comment: @PigBoT Good catch, was added in a revision by Abdulla Nilam, not sure why, maybe it was required in a specific version of Angular. Either way, I have reverted it back to the original answer :)

Comment: Erex, probably just some confusion on his part.  I scanned the doc versions, all but Dart, and only saw one argument.  Answer looks good to me now.  Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it used to have two arguments ('name', control);

Answer (score 9):

I tried Adhikari answer but could not worked for me, it always throw error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'addControl' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

His answer helped me to think, and finally I came out with this:

Write a getter property anywhere like this (to get the group):

```
get addressGroup() { return this.candidateForm.get('address'); }
```

Now wherever you want to add some controls, use like this:

```
if(this.addressGroup instanceof FormGroup){
   var ctrl:AbstractControl = this.fBuilder.control('', [Validators.required]);
   (<FormGroup>this.addressGroup).addControl('address3', ctrl);

   var emailCtrl:AbstractControl = this.fBuilder.control('', [Validators.email]);
   (<FormGroup>this.addressGroup).addControl('myEmail', emailCtrl);

   var add4:AbstractControl = this.fBuilder.control('', []);
   (<FormGroup>this.addressGroup).addControl('address4', add4);
}
```

It is an old question, but hope this will help someone!

Comment: Same goes for 'removeControl' also:
(<FormGroup>this.addressGroup).removeControl('address4', add4);

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
(this.candidateForm.get('address') as FormGroup).addControl('address3', this.formBuilder.control(null));
(this.candidateForm.get('address') as FormGroup).removeControl('address3');
```