# Remove object inside nested form groups

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I m  working in angular reactive forms project . I need to remove an  object inside nested form groups

```
this.surveyForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null],
      _id: [null],
      question: [null],
      from_list: [true],
      type: CampaignActivityType.Survey,
      questionList:this.fb.group({
      question: ['', Validators.required],
      answers:this.fb.group({
      answer: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    });
)
    });
```

I  need to remove answer object in a specific index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add/remove FormControl from a nested FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293093/how-to-add-remove-formcontrol-from-a-nested-formgroup)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Remove:
this.surveyForm.get('answers').removeControl('answer');
```